# 13.04 flickering mouse pointer

Tags: 13.04, mouse, overheating, cursor, flicker

I'm running 13.04 on my laptop. My laptop has a tendency to run really hot - to the point of thermal shutdowns if left unattended for a long period of time. I don't know if that's relevant. the mouse cursor flickers constantly. Sometimes it disappears altogether. The flickering is about 1Hz at rest, but as I do things or type it increases in frequency. It looks like every time the system registers a keypress it flickers. How can i fix this or diagnose what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered [previously](https://askubuntu.com/a/360473/280643).

> I had the same problem. You can fix it manually.  Open `System
>   Settings > Displays`.  In the `Displays` window, you will see an
>   `Unknown monitor`.  Click it and disable it.