# Mouse cursor flickering and disappearing

Tags: cursor

I installed Ubuntu today and since the first start up I have a problem with the mouse cursor.

It starts randomly disappearing and flickering a lot.

I have searched for a solution on Google and here but didn't find anything.

Comment: Welcome! How is your mouse connected (USB maybe)? Try with another mouse device and see what happens. Also you may try plugging into another port

Comment: Its happening in 14.04 as well and this trick saved my time.

Comment: if you are having flickering in chrome only , try this answer, adding one section to the 20-intel.conf file fixed my issues with flicker in chrome.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/766725/annoying-flickering-in-16-04-lts-chrome#768112

Answer (score 209):

I had the same problem. You can fix it manually.

Open **System Settings > Displays**.

In the **Displays** window, you will see an **Unknown monitor**.

Click it and disable it.

Comment: And to remove that screen you can follow this: http://askubuntu.com/a/365017/34385

Comment: Great! How did you figure out??

Comment: There is no unknown display for me. But I can see 2 built in display in red and green color. I tried disabling one of those alternatively but that also didn't solved my issue. Please help

Comment: Ho sorry... Disabling the green built in display solved the issue. 
Thanks

Comment: This didn't work in my case (I had no "Unknown Monitor"). I have posted [a question here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/552017/mouse-flickers-and-computer-is-unresponsive-while-mouse-is-moving) but given that the OP is a superset of my question I think this answer should provide other possible solutions (or at least avenues to investigate).

Comment: Is there a way to open this menu from the command-line? I'm using IceWM.

Comment: I've just upgraded to 16.10 - the pointer flickers but there is no unknown monitor...

Comment: This does not work if your second monitor is real and in-use

Comment: I only have one display, that is unknown display. There is no built-in-display in my case..

Comment: I have "unknown display", no way to "click it and disable it". Running ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

**Possible cause 1:**

Screen settings: resolution and refresh rate.
Can be checked (On KDE) under `systemsettings5` then `display and monitor`

**Possible cause 2:**

Screen compositor: it could be caused by the sale-method/rendering-backend/tearing-prevention those settings can be changed (On KDE) under `systemsettings5`, `display and monitor` then `compositor`... apply new settings and compare

**Possible cause 3:**

Display server mis-configuration: you can regenerate the display server config file with `X -configure` or similar **but** first make a copy of `/etc/X11`

**Possible cause 4:**

System failure, crash, reboot: on system failure especially for systems equipped with SSD you may loose important files; Files under directories like `/home/user/`, `/etc/` or `/usr/` can cause serious damages,  as these directories contain important settings/packages files for different aspect of the desktop. usually when a file is lost after a crash, the file may be completely deleted or zeroed, you can then search for file with zero size and check out if important file are corrupted with the command `find /etc -size 0 -print` (this is for /etc) you can also check packages integrity for missing/modified file, on rpm based system it's done with the command `rpm -Va` you would then reinstall the broken package.

A common situation in this case is loosing the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` or one of the config file under `/etc/X11/` responsible for the display server; If recovering the file is not possible the config can be regenerated with `X -configure` or similar command

**Possible cause 5:**

Mis-configuration of user files under `/home/user`... you can verify this by login with an other user... to fix it eventually delete and recreate the user (after backup)

**Possible cause 7:**

Graphic drivers, you need to check if you are using the proper graphic driver and or try a different version of the used driver, usually this often happen with nvidia graphical cards.

**Other...**

The listed situations are not the only possibilities of failure.

*Source: [Linuxhacks.org](https://linuxhacks.org/how-to-fix-mouse-cursor-flickering-or-disappearing/)

Disclosure: I am the owner of Linuxhacks.org*

Answer (score 0):

I ran, from within 16.04, the command:

```
  sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and it seems to have appeased the pointer, so far. 
I had instability, especially over the Chrome browser tabs.

Answer (score 0):

2020 - Ubuntu 18.04

The problem here was because of I have Dell's laptop and Dells's Monitor, there isn't any "unknown display".

The Ubuntu wasn't recognizing the laptop as "built in".

After setup everything and restart the laptop, all works fine.

Comment: "After setup everything" What does this mean? Can you share more context to what you set up? Tried rebooting several times, does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by changing my monitor setup using randr. It turned out that my second screen had a rather large offset to the first one (instead of being directly adjacent). My best guess is that this creates a large mostly unused framebuffer that also covers the area between the screens, which may be problematic?

You can either use a tool like `arandr` to place the screens without a gap in a GUI or run `xrandr` on the command line like so

`xrandr --output HDMI-1 --left-of DP-1`
(replace your respective monitor outputs, you can find out their name by running `xrandr` without arguments)