# Clean install to Saucy reduces to low-graphics mode and flickering mouse cursor

Tags: graphics, 13.10

My laptop used to work perfectly with Ubuntu 13.04 but, after upgrading to 13.10, I am greeted by a flickering underscore in the top left corner of a black screen instead of LigthDM. It quickly moves on to the low graphics mode dialogue and then, after I opt for low graphics mode, starts GDM (which I installed). But the unity desktop I get from this has no mouse cursor (although I can still click on things if I work out where the cursor should be) and is very slow to animate the dash etc. My NVidia drivers are up to date, and the Intel graphics driver seems to be installed as well so can anyone help me resolve this issue and get full hardware-accelerated graphics back?

Comment: With the mouse cursor, you might be able to change the theme so that you can actually see it - use Ubuntu Tweak or something. Also, you could switch the login screen to start GDM instead LightDM. I know that you can do this in Fedora using `sudo system-switch-displaymanager gdm`, which might work in Ubuntu - but if not, hopefully some Ubuntu equivalent might turn up (sorry). Do not know what to do about the hardware-accelerated graphics. Even reinstalling might help.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed [Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation)? Usually it solves the nvidia graphics issues in a "smooth way".

And here is something about the [mouse cursor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360423/mouse-cursor-flickering-and-disappearing?rq=1)