# Ubuntu 13.10 Mirror Display Error

Tags: 13.10, multiple-monitors, display

I've just upgraded my Ubuntu to 13.10 Saucy using dist-upgrade. After upgrading, I can't mirror my display when connected to a projector. It seems that it is related to [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360423/mouse-cursor-flickering-and-disappearing). Any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by login using Gnome flashback (no effect) session. It seems that compiz is the cause of this problem.