# Netflix desktop mouse pointer issue

Tags: netflix

Once I open the netflix-desktop the mouse pointer vanishes and doesn't appear even after I close the application. Only way I get it back is after I logoff-login.

This is the only reason I hesitate to log into Ubuntu and have to go into windows. Please help if you know solution.

I have Ubuntu 13.10.

Thanks, KK

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. I've ran into the same problem and it took a little tinkering. Hope this gets you started.

regards,
somacomadreams

[Mouse Flickering and Disappearing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360423/mouse-cursor-flickering-and-disappearing)

Comment: I don't see any unknown monitor. There is only one.

Comment: What type of machine are you using? Is it a macbook?

Comment: Dell Inspiron - dual boot Windows 8/Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: I remember seeing a thread about this exact problem, except the mouse was flickering at all times. Let me see if I can dig it up for you.

Comment: I have a touchscreen laptop so I can just touch anywhere on the screen so my issue is resolved temporarily. I will keep this question open in case someone can find an actual answer. Thanks for your time and help! ~Thanks,KK