# Ubuntu 14.04 touchpad detected but not working

Tags: 14.04, unity, xorg, touchpad, synaptics

I am currently using a Toshiba Satellite P850-138 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I've been running Ubuntu on this laptop for about 3 years without any issues related to the touchpad until now.

I was running Rstudio and attempting to install the package "rgl". The installation failed due to the following error:

```
checking for X... no
configure: error: X2 not found but required, configure aborted.
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'rgl'
```

On the basis of this thread:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=787464 I tried to install xserver-xorg-dev, but ran into the following error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Despite the fact that my current versions of libcheese-gtk23 and libcheese7 are 3.10.2, and so shouldn't cause an issue.

This bug has already been reported (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1428972) and the advice in the comments suggested running

```
sudo apt-get install canonical-certification-client libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl15 libclutter-gst-2.0-0 gstreamer1.0-clutter
```

But after running this, I still had the same bug with installing xserver-xorg-dev.

I decided to try to install xserver using the synaptic package manager, which I'm pretty sure is the point where I messed everything up. I chose to install xserver-xorg-dev, and didn't pay attention to the packages that were going to be removed in the process of the installation.

Synaptic installed xserver-xorg-dev, removed other packages and finished. I installed 'rgl' in R with no issue.

When I next restarted the laptop, there was no visible cursor and the touchpad didn't work. This thread ([Ubuntu 14.04 no cursor after fresh instalation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450449/ubuntu-14-04-no-cursor-after-fresh-instalation)) prompted me to have a look in System Settings, only for me to find out I didn't have unity-control-center anymore. I reinstalled unity-control-center which fixed the cursor issue, but the touchpad is still not responding.

xinput shows that the touchpad is detected:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Toshiba input device                      id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` also returns information on the touchpad:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01b1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event5 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=660800011000003
```

`lsmod` shows psmouse, which I think is the touchpad, but it isn't being used by anything:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   20480  2 
rfcomm                 69632  8 
nouveau              1368064  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    81920  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          36864  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_hda_controller     32768  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         143360  5      snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  4    snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
intel_rapl             20480  0 
iosf_mbi               16384  1 intel_rapl
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0 
intel_powerclamp       20480  0 
coretemp               16384  0 
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
snd_seq_midi           16384  0 
ttm                    94208  1 nouveau
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
kvm_intel             151552  0 
arc4                   16384  2 
kvm                   479232  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0 
crc32_pclmul           16384  0 
rtl8723ae              86016  0 
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
btcoexist              53248  1 rtl8723ae
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0 
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723ae
cryptd                 20480  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8723ae
rtlwifi                73728  2 rtl_pci,rtl8723ae
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
mac80211              708608  2 rtl_pci,rtlwifi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
joydev                 20480  0 
serio_raw              16384  0 
snd                    86016  17  snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_s eq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
i915                 1048576  3 
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0 
cfg80211              524288  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
btusb                  40960  0 
lpc_ich                24576  0 
bluetooth             491520  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
mei_me                 20480  0 
drm_kms_helper        126976  2 i915,nouveau
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
drm                   344064  8 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
soundcore              16384  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
shpchp                 40960  0 
toshiba_acpi           28672  0 
toshiba_bluetooth      16384  0 
toshiba_haps           16384  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 toshiba_acpi
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,nouveau
ene_ir                 24576  0 
rc_core                28672  1 ene_ir
mac_hid                16384  0 
video                  20480  2 i915,nouveau
wmi                    20480  3 toshiba_acpi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
parport_pc             32768  0 
ppdev                  20480  0 
lp                     20480  0 
parport                45056  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_generic            16384  0 
usbhid                 53248  0 
hid                   110592  2 hid_generic,usbhid
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0 
psmouse               114688  0 
ahci                   36864  2 
libahci                32768  1 ahci
r8169                  81920  0 
rtsx_pci               49152  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
mii                    16384  1 r8169
```

Removing and reattaching the touchpad with

```
xinput float "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
xinput reattach "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Virtual core pointer"
```

doesn't work, and neither does

```
sudo modprobe -rv psmouse proto=imps
sudo modprobe -v psmouse proto=imps
```

I can't find any more threads on this topic online, and I can't think of anything else to try.

Answer (score 1):

Your probably removed a huge portion of your system when you installed the xserver-xorg-dev package. At this point you can either try to fix your current system, or save your files and re-install the whole system. 
As from my understanding you essentially installed files to support the one package, that overwrite/remove your normal stable operating system.

So the problem is not directly related to the touchpad, rather its now your operating system as a whole. Fixing the mouse would be fine, but you might end up with further problems with installing other software that gets confused with your mixed operating system.

I am pretty trigger happy when it comes to re-installing Ubuntu on my machines, and because you have had the system for 3 years I suggest waiting before completely nuking your setup. Goodluck!