# Why is my mouse invisible on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, xserver

I'm running a clean installation of 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 with dual monitors. When I start up the mouse is invisible on the login screen and after logging in. Relogging in does not work.

I've googled around and there seems to be the following two general suggestions

https://askubuntu.com/a/455651/235211

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

and http://itsfoss.com/invisible-mouse-cursor-ubuntu-1310/

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

Neither of which resolved my problem. It was only fixed after restarting the xserver.

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

This fixes the problem. But the problem reappears after restarting my computer. I could reload the server on every setup, but that seems like a poor bandaid solution rather than fixing the core issue.

What can I do to resolve the issue or further debug it?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had an invisible mouse which was cured by one of these three processes.  Not sure which one cured it.  I'll have to test them if I have the problem again to see.

The first two were terminal commands: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Cntl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

**First:**

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

**Second:**

```
$ dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/cursor/active false
```

**Third:**

Install and run [Unity-Tweak-Tool](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=unity-tweak-tool&searchon=names&suite=wily&section=all) then change the cursor settings to different settings and back:
 `Dmz-black` > `Dmz-white` > `Redglass` > `Dmz-black`

Answer (score 0):

I'd tried the common suggestions: `gsettings`, `dconf`, `modprobe`, none of which solved it for me running Lubuntu 15.04 and Lubuntu 16.04.

What worked was removing the `silent splash` option from grub.  (Easy way to do this is by installing [Grub Customizer](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-1404/)).  The aforementioned solutions may have contributed to solving the issue, but I found removing `silent splash` to be the missing puzzle piece.