# Mouse cursor flickering solution not working

Tags: 14.04, mouse, cursor

I installed ubuntu 14.04 and there is a problem with mouse flickering

I know that there is a thread with this question
[Mouse cursor flickering and disappearing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360423/mouse-cursor-flickering-and-disappearing)
but once i disable the unknown display... the flickering disappears..

but my screen size is 60% of what it used to be..
i have 20% dead band (black vertical bands) on right and left portion of my screen...

its terrible..

Comment: What's your video card?

Comment: its nvidia geforce mobile 6500 series i suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about that, initially the drop down menu for aspect ratio and resolution did not work...

but a system restart fixed it...

really sorry for troubles of anyone