# Ubuntu 12.04 in VMware split screen issue after updating

Tags: 12.04, vmware-player

I have Ubuntu installed on VMware player.

After installing the last updates the screen went like this image:
[image]

As you see I have **not real** second Menu(it is not clickable)

Why did this happen and how to fix?

Comment: I can't add an answer since the question has been protected, but VMWare has an explanation and several possible solutions here: https://communities.vmware.com/message/2398873#2398873 Just changing the VM Hardware version worked for me - no need to downgrade anything.

Answer (score 3):

I used my VM previous snapshot to reproduce the problem.

Previous kernel: 3.2.0-63. VM running ok.

1) I applied all updates (including openssl) but NOT the kernel. After rebooting, **the VM screen is OK**.

2) I updated again (only the kernel packages, version 3.2.0-64 were pending: complete kernel, headers and kernel image) and rebooted: split / doubled screen shows up!

3) I ran vmware-config-tools.pl in other to generate modules for the new kernel and rebooted:  the split screen persists. Not solved.

4) also tried a full VM power off / power on: the problem persists.

It seems to be definitely a kernel 3.2.0-64 - related issue.

Suggestion: apply all updates (the openssl update is critical), but skip the kernel packages for now, until we get a fix from VMware or the Ubuntu team.

(AND: ALWAYS create a snapshot before you update anything !!)

---

See also these threads:

https://communities.vmware.com/message/2388587#2388587

https://communities.vmware.com/thread/481038

In summary:  if you don't have a previous snapshot, either enable the grub menu on boot and choose a previous kernel (e.g. 3.2.0-63) or: using the package manager, uninstall the kernel 3.2.0-64 and RE-INSTALL the previous kernel (this will take care of grub and boot configs).

Let's wait for a fix. And don't update the kernel for now.

Answer (score 3):

Confirmed - Same issue with VMWare Workstation 10.0.2 with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Solved with:

```
sudo apt-get remove 3.2.0-64
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the answer described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360423/mouse-cursor-flickering-and-disappearing) :

Open System Settings > Displays. In the Displays window, you will see an Unknown monitor. Click it and disable it.

Answer (score 2):

Since the 14.04LTS question was marked as a duplicate of this one, the solution for 14.04LTS is very similar.

To fix this issue on 14.04LTS I used the following:

```
 sudo apt-get remove 3.13.0-29-generic
 sudo update-grub
 sudo shutdown -r now
```

This reverted the kernel to `3.13.0-27-generic` which does not exhibit the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have 14.04LTS on vmplayer, and for me help removing 3.13.0-30-generic

```
sudo apt-get remove 3.13.0-30-generic
sudo update-grub
sudo shutdown -r now
```