# Display Problems running Ubuntu 12.04 in Windows VMware Player

Tags: windows-7, video, display, vmware-player

I am posting this again because I have changed to VMWare Player and I discovered something new.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Guest) in VMWare Player 6.0.2 on Windows 7 64-bit Host. 
I have VMWare Tools installed properly.
I am running MATE but the problem persists when I change (to and from) xfce, gnome, mate a-- and back again
I had been using this for a couple of years without any graphics issues.
After an Ubuntu update (typical) -- my video is corrupt and will not refresh correctly.

My desktop icons are "mirrored" and when I open a terminal window (for instance) -- sometimes -- the window appears multiple times.
Of course, only one is the real image.  It seems to be a refresh problem.
When I move an active window around the screen the "older" images "erase" and my icons (for instance) are in the correct location.
For instance, I can move the terminal around a pretty corrupted window and the screen behind it is repainted correctly.

NEW:

Next, I got the idea to try and Remote Desktop in to the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Guest OS from my Windows 7 64-bit Host.

Once working, and connected via Win RDC -- using MATE as default in my /etc/xrdp/startws.sh -- my video is not corrupted and works fine (as in the past).

Any ideas about what is going on ? or how to fix this ?

Comment: Since remote desktop works fine, the problem is either the VMware GPU driver in Ubuntu, or VMware, or Windows GPU driver. You could try Ubuntu 14.04 and if the bug still occurs report it to VMware. Or use VirtualBox.

Comment: You could also try disabling the 3D graphics checkbox in VM Settings > Display.

Comment: [Ubuntu 12.04 screen issue after updating](http://askubuntu.com/questions/480758/ubuntu-12-04-screen-issue-after-updating)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same "mirroring" problem after updating my vmware 64 bit Ubuntu. The previous version was fine. I fixed the problem by copying

```
/lib/modules/3.2.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/vmwgfx/vmwgfx.ko
```

to

```
/lib/modules/3.2.0-65-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/vmwgfx/vmwgfx.ko
```

After renaming the original driver under 3.2.0-65. I don't know at what version the driver broke since "30" was the previous version that I had. 32 bit Ubuntu exhibited the same problem after updating. Downgrading the driver as above fixed it as well.