# Ubuntu 14.04 in VMware Workstation split screen issue after updating

Tags: 14.04, updates, screen, vmware

After updating and restarting my Ubuntu 14.04, I get a split screen, similarly to the issue describe at [Ubuntu 12.04 in VMware split screen issue after updating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/480758/ubuntu-12-04-screen-issue-after-updating/480939#480939)

I'm running it on VMware Workstation 7.1.4, my host is Windows 7 and kernel version is *3.13.0-45-generic* .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I found the exact kernel version using `uname -r` , then I applied the downgrade fix:

```
 sudo apt-get remove 3.13.0-45-generic
 sudo update-grub
 sudo shutdown -r now
```

After restarting, it still didn't get fixed, so I reran it again, now downgrading it from `3.13.0-44-generic`. After the reboot, **it worked fine**, and my current version is `3.13.0-24-generic`.

*Disclaimer: the solution is similar to [Ubuntu 12.04 in VMware split screen issue after updating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/480758/ubuntu-12-04-screen-issue-after-updating/486927#486927). I decided to add a question and answer here anyway, because it didn't work on the first iteration.*

Comment: Adding another question and answer is helpful because you are using VMware Workstation instead of VMware Player and Ubuntu 14.04 guest OS instead of Ubuntu 12.04, so your answer helps VMware users to keep up to date.