# Can't boot into 14.04 in VMware Workstation 10

Tags: boot, vmware-workstation

Right after I enter my password the VM gets stuck at this point. I tried Ctrl+Alt+F2 and restarting lightdm. I also tried changing the amount of RAM. I also have the "update your vmware tools" tooltip but I doubt it is relevant.

Here is where it is stuck:

[image]

Comment: The tiling effect you have in VMware Workstation looks similar to [Ubuntu 12.04 in VMware split screen issue after updating](http://askubuntu.com/questions/480758/ubuntu-12-04-in-vmware-split-screen-issue-after-updating) or [Ubuntu 14.04 in VMware Workstation split screen issue after updating](http://askubuntu.com/questions/581717/ubuntu-14-04-split-screen-issue-after-updating).