# How do I fix Ubuntu 18.04 with a split screen?

Tags: boot

I lost a HP yesterday to an attempted Ubuntu installation. I'm still struggling to figure that out.

I got my hands on a Lenovo ideapad 330. 8 GB RAM, Ryzen 3 chil, 1TB SSD Windows 10 installed. Partitioned disk in half. Seemed reasonable to do. I intend spending most of my time in Linux.

I used a USB boot image for Ubuntu 18.04 as described in installation procedure. Installation commenced and first thing I see is a split screen. Like the screen is split down the middle, trying to scroll the mouse results in it partially appearing on both screens intermittently.
As a result it's cumbersome. Note that the entire contents of each screen are not visible. Almost as if 3/4 of one screen are covered by the other screen which is also incomplete.

I'm explaining this as vividly as I can because I am not allowed to post images apparently because i'm a newbie on here. I attempted navigating blind but it only got worse.

I shut down and tried again, same thing.
I made another boot USB with 16.04 iso image.
Same thing. I sense some hardware incompatibility. Not sure.

Please has anyone else experienced this? Need help.
Thank you.

Bootup image of Ubuntu 18.04 with splitscreen effect
[image: Bootup image of Ubuntu 18.04 with splitscreen effect]

Comment: Hello. I've never experienced this kind of problem (sounds like a video drivers bug to me), but could You post some photo presenting it?

Comment: Just successfully added the image. What usually happens is when I create the post on my mobile, it doesnt let me add an image stating my points are low. And then I edit on my pC and it lets me add the image. Strange.

Comment: So it looks like someone experienced something similar here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/480758/ubuntu-12-04-in-vmware-split-screen-issue-after-updating But it was for VMware