# Ubuntu 14.10 Cursor Broken after upgrade from 14.04

Tags: upgrade, gui, cursor, 14.10

I encountered this problem after upgraded from 14.04,
after I rebooted, my cursor is broken.

Whenever I move my cursor, their would be several cursors flashing and jumping on my screen, it also does this when I am typing or even I am not doing anything.

I have reinstalled 14.04 and upgraded it to 14.10 again, and the problem still occurred,
but this time occurred after the second time I rebooted.

The other part of computer is fine, maybe is the UI problem or something, but I cannot find similar problem.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I might have had a similar problem. Can you try installing ibus-gtk and let me know how that goes? sudo apt-get install ibus-gtk (in a terminal)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mouse cursor flickering and disappearing](http://askubuntu.com/questions/360423/mouse-cursor-flickering-and-disappearing)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

On Grub, press <kbd>e</kbd> and append `acpi=off` in linux line.

Ex: `linux  /vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic root=/dev/mapper/sda1 ro acpi=off`

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and wait for the system to boot.

Comment: What does acpi has to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Was getting the same issue. For me going into Settings / Screen Display and making sure only 1 display was active fixed the problem

Comment: How do I fix it if I'm not using Ubuntu's default desktop environment?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after upgrading to 14.10.  My cursor was completely invisible.  Instead of the pointer appearance flickering between multiple different ones, it was stuck on an invisible one.  This might not be the same as the problem you're describing.

I found the solution at 
https://faq.i3wm.org/question/4843/cursor-has-disappeared-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-1410/?answer=4848#post-id-4848

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false` fixed it

`gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active` before doing that showed that it had been `true`.

I've had this /home since Ubuntu 7.04 or so, so there's a lot of cruft.