# My Macbook has two "Built-In Displays"

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, macbook

I just installed 14.04 on my Macbook Pro 8,2 and I noticed that I have two "Built-In displays". Some applications open on the second display with no way to get to them. If I disable either display, I get no image on my screen.

I'm also having trouble with my mouse pointer flickering which others have fixed by disabling a phantom "Unknown Display" : ([Mouse cursor flickering and disappearing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360423/mouse-cursor-flickering-and-disappearing)). For me though, my phantom display is a secondary "Built-In" display.

Any idea how to properly remove the extra display?

Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6m9n1f4nq8rqgms/Built-in.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this for anyone who comes across this issue in the future. Apparently having power to both the integrated and discrete graphics cards was causing each to create a display, resulting in two Built-in displays and mouse flickering.

I turned off the intigrated graphics by doing:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

And add the following lines:

```
chown "username" /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch # change "username" with your user name
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

Then reboot.

When I now run `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` I get the following result and no more second monitor/mouse flickering.

```
0:IGD: :Off:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS-Audio: :Pwr:0000:01:00.1
2:DIS:+:Pwr:0000:01:00.0
```

`

Comment: Excellent answer!  Upvoted!

Comment: perfect solution , work with Ubuntu 22 and macbook Pro 2011

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: my first answer (kept at the end for posterity) isn't great, so I ended up with the following instead.*

### Disabling the phantom display in X

I encountered a this issue on a MacBook Pro 5,3 running Ubuntu 20.04, but without the flickering cursor. Running `echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` caused my system to freeze for some reason, so I had to find another fix. The one I landed on was to [disable the "phantom" display in the X configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr#Disabling_phantom_monitor).

First, work out the identifier of the phantom display with `xrandr`:

```sh
$ xrandr --listmonitors
```

This should show two displays, one of which is the phantom one. In my case it showed `LVDS-1` and `LVDS-1-2`. I guessed that `LVDS-1-2` was phantom because `LVDS-1` had a `*` next to it, but I'm not sure if that's the right way to tell. In any case, verify your guess by turning it off with `xrandr`:

```sh
$ xrandr --output LVDS-1-2 --off
```

If that works, you can then make it permanent in the X configuration. Create a new file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`:

```sh
$ sudoedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/01-disable-phantom-screen.conf
```

...and put the following in it, replacing `LVDS-1-2` with the ID of your phantom screen:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "LVDS-1-2"
    Option "Ignore" "true"
EndSection
```

After this, though, I still had the problem on the login screen (GDM), and in fact it was worse because GDM was showing its UI on the phantom screen. To fix this, [force GDM to use X](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#Use_Xorg_backend) by editing `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` to remove the `#` from `#WaylandEnable=false`. (If you happen to be using [Ubuntu's OEM install mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview), there'll also be a `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf.oem` file. You'll want to change that, too, so that the fix persists once the end user completes the setup wizard.)

### Old answer: disable Nouveau

*Like I said above, this answer isn't great (turns out disabling your graphics driver is rather bad for performance), but I've kept it here in case it helps someone.*

I disabled `vgaswitcheroo` entirely. To do this, add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in `/etc/default/grub`. For example, mine looks like this afterwards:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"
```

Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

The [HybridGraphics page in the community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) has more details that helped me work this out.