# mouse glitching and disappearing&reappearing

Tags: mouse, mate

**hi,first question here**
some days ago i installed Ubuntu mate,and i directly customized it for my needs,but today the started glitching,disappearing,and just freezing sometimes,this happened also on the deafult cursor,so i don't think is the custom cursor [these responses didn't help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360423/mouse-cursor-flickering-and-disappearing)